# how to print results of sqlite3 on html using flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Good Day fellow developers. I have been googling for hours and reading documents for a while but i cant seem to print the contents of allmodels into the html file

```
#python file
@app.route('/models')
#@login_required
def models(): 
    allmodels = Modeldb.query.all() #THIS RETURNS A LIST FORM SQLITE3
    return render_template('models.html', allmodels=allmodels)
```

here is the html file

```
<html>
<head>

<body class = "body">

<body>
<h1> HELLOO </h1>


{% for models in allmodels %}
<p> {{ models }} </p>
{% endfor %}


</body>

</head>
</html>
```

and it outputs

HELLOO  
<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0bcc>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0c8c>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0c0c>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0ccc>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0d0c>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0d4c>

<**main**.Modeldb object at 0xb5db0d8c>

I know im close. or maybe not. :) thanks in advance and more energy to you guys ;))))

Answer (score 0):

okay. soo i figured it out.

```
 {% for models in allmodels %}
 {{row["column_name_here"]}} 
 {{row["another_column_name_here_if_u_want"]}} 
 {% endfor %}
```

this basically did the thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out :). Not able to comment yet, so adding this post with alternative syntax:

```
{% for models in allmodels %}
    {{models.column_name_here}} 
    {{models.column2_name_here}} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative syntax. it was more readable and easy to understand compared to mine :))